# Viewing source after adding new row in <table>

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dojo

I am creating new row in `<table>` through javascript. Row is added but I cannot view source code of the newly created row through **Developer Tools in internet Explorer**. I can view it through firebug in Firefox.

Problem is I am working on drag and drop in dojo of these rows. Any rows that are already in the table can be drag and drop but when I create a new row then after generation new row could not be drag and drop because its not added to the source code and dojo could not find that row to be dragged.

This is the code for new row creation.

```
var tbody = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var row = tbody.insertRow(rowCount);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

var element2 = document.createElement('input');    
element2.value = "valueHere";
element2.type = "text";

cell1.appendChild(element2);
row.appendChild(cell1);
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

When I try to drag new row Dojo gives error

```
'getItem(...).type' is null or not an object
```

Comment: When calling [insertRow](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-39872903), you do not have to append the row, it is part of the *insertRow* method. Same for [insertCell](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-68927016) (i.e. the last two lines of the script are redundant).

Comment: Thanks RobG but my questions persists.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't alter your code, it alters the DOM. Hence why you won't see it in the source view in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem that dojo was not updating it draggable nodes. Also by viewing source was not displaying newly created rows. Dojo dnd source has a property called **autoSync**. See [dojo.dnd.Source api](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dojo/dnd/Source). Its by default set to false but enabling it true does the work. It automatically syncs the nodes and all newly generated nodes was able to drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely after new row is added you need to reinitiate you plugin

Comment: You mean re initiate developer tools. It works after refreshing developer tools. but still not dragging dropping.